# How to detect no voice from user and run the next audio file in Html5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make my little project like AI, what I mean is I have a some audio files as an array. And I use annyang API as a voice command to start running the program. After the first audio file is done playing. The program pauses. And I will say some sentenses until the program detects no voice from me for 3 seconds(or even longer). It will play the second audio file and then pause again. This program will loop until all audio files have played. Is there anyway to do this?

Here is my code so far.

```
    <script>                          
        if (annyang) 
        {

            var commands = {

            '1': function() 
            {   
                var playList = ["1_hello", "2_how_old", "3_what_did_you_make"]

                var dir = "sound/";
                var extention = ".wav";
                var index = 1;
                var count = 4;

                var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

                if(agent.indexOf('firefox') != -1 || agent.indexOf('opera') != -1)
                    {
                        extention = ".wav";
                    }

                audio = new Audio();

                audio.src = dir + playList[0] + extention;
                audio.load();
                setTimeout(function(){audio.play();}, 1000);

                audio.onended = function()
                {
                    if(index < playList.length)
                    {
                            audio.src = dir + playList[index] + extention;
                            audio.load();
                            setTimeout(function(){audio.play();}, 1000);
                            index++;


                    }
                }

                audio.loop = false;
            }
        };

        annyang.debug(true);

        annyang.addCommands(commands);  

        }

    </script>
```

I have found a [visualizing sound](http://www.smartjava.org/content/exploring-html5-web-audio-visualizing-sound) that might do it, but I'm not sure how.

I have been struggling with this for a week. And Can't really find solutions for this. I'm open to jQuery as well. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Thank you for replying. My question is, is there anyway I can make my program detect no voice for around 3 seconds after play the first audio file, and then play the second audio file?

Comment: What do you mean detect no voice? Are you trying to read audio from a microphone or are you trying to detect if the audio file has stopped playing for 3 seconds?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear. What I mean is after the first audio from my array has played, my code would pause because I will talk to the web app. And while I'm talking to the web app, it's trying to detect my voice volumn. Once I finished talking, it doesn't detect any voice. Thus, the web app knows I finish talking. Once the web app knows I finish talking, it will play the second audio file from my array.

Comment: Does this make more sense to you? I'm sorry if I made you confused more. If I do, please let me know. Thank you so much.

Comment: Makes things much clearer.

Comment: Do you have any code for using the api? if so can you post it.

Comment: I think You should wait 5-10 seconds until You get the voice command

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Thank you. I'll notice myself from now on.

Comment: @num8er I think so as well. But right now I set 1 second is for testing

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `annyang.addCallback` and `annyang.addRemoveback` to add or remove callbacks for events `annyang` fires.

According to the API documentation the event we are probably intested in is `soundstart` https://github.com/TalAter/annyang/blob/master/docs/README.md

> `soundstart` - Fired as soon as any sound (possibly speech) has been
>   detected. This will fire once per Speech Recognition starting.

We can add or remove call backs to fire when this event is fired.

When can track when these events were fired and execute logic to play a song if more than 3 seconds has elapsed.

Here is some baseline psuedo code. I don't have a microphone so I can test.

```
var monitorId=0;
function monitorSound()
{
    if(monitorId&& monitorId>0) return;
    monitorId=window.setInterval(trackSound,1000);
}
var lastSound= new Date();
function trackSound() {
    var now = new Date();
    if (now-lastSound)>3000)
    {
        stopListening();
        playNextAudio();
        return;
    }
}

function startListening() {
    annyang.addCallback('startsound', onSoundHeard);
}
function stopListening() 
{
    // stop the loop tracking when the last sound was heard.
    window.clearInterval(monitorId);
    monitorId=0;
    // Remove onSoundHeard from being called on start:
    annyang.removeCallback('startsound', onSoundHeard);
}

var playList = ['mydir/mysong1.wav','mydir/mysong2.wav','mydir/mysong2.wav'];
var audioIndex=0;
function playNextAudio(){
    if(index==playList.length-1) return; -- we have played all audio
    // play the next audio
    audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = playList[index++];
    audio.load();
    setTimeout(function(){audio.play();}, 1000);

    audio.onended = startListening

}
function onSoundHeard() {
    lastSound= new Date();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander. Right now I got a problem that doesn't listen to any voice command and it auto play the first audio based on your psuedo code. I'm trying to figure out. If I have more questions, I will let you know. Thanks for the big hint.

Comment: Alexander, I have another question. Would you mind to take a look at it, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45094342/how-to-make-annyang-detect-no-sound-for-3-seconds-or-longer-then-start-next-aud Thank you