# How to make annyang detect no sound for 3 seconds or longer, then start next audio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a person's help to build this so far. But my goal is after the first audio file, the program would still listen what the user says until the user finishes talking. And then if the program doesn't detect anything for 3 seconds(or longer), it will play the next audio. This program will do this over and over until all audio files have played.

However, there's one more case. If the user is a 2 years old kid, which means the kid might need to spend 2 seconds or longer between 2 sentences. In this case, the annyang might think the user has finished their sentences and play next audio. This way the program would interrupt the user speech. How should I handle this?

That person who gave me ideas of using setInverval and create some date objects and then minus date objects to get a time greater than 3 seconds, and play next audio. But it's not working. Is my logic of code wrong or there's a better way?

Any help I would appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

```
  <script>               
        audio = new Audio();

        if (annyang) 
        {
            annyang.addCallback('start', function() {console.log('started listening!');});
            annyang.addCallback('soundstart', function(){onSoundDetected();});

            function monitorSound()
            {
                if(monitorId && monitorId > 0) return;
                var monitorId = window.setInterval(function(){trackSound() }, 1000);
            }

            var lastSound= new Date();

            function trackSound() 
            {
                var now = new Date();

                if ((now - lastSound) > 3000)
                {
                    playNextAudio();
                    return;
                }
            }

            function stopListening()
            {
                var monitorId = 0;
                window.clearInterval(monitorId);

                annyang.removeCallback('soundstart', onSoundHeard);
                annyang.addCallback('result', function() {playNextAudio(); });
            }

            function onSoundHeard() 
            {
                lastSound = new Date();
                console.log(lastSound);
            }

            function playNextAudio()
            {                    
                if(audioIndex === playList.length - 1) 
                {
                    console.log("Played all audios");
                    return; // we have played all audio
                }
                else
                {
                    annyang.addCallback('result', function() {
                        audio.src = dir + playList[audioIndex++] + extention;
                        audio.load();
                        //audio.ended = audio.play();
                        //audio.ended = setTimeout(function(){audio.play();}, 1500);
                        setTimeout(function(){audio.play();}, 1000);
                    });
                }

            }

            function playFirstAudio()
            {
                audio.src = dir + playList[audioIndex] + extention;
                audio.load();
                audio.ended = setTimeout(function(){audio.play();}, 1000);
                console.log('First audio is playing');

            }

            function onSoundDetected() 
            {
                console.log('sound was detected');

                playFirstAudio();
                monitorSound();
            }

            // Start from here

            var playList = ["1_hello", "2_how_old", "3_what_did_you_make"];
            var dir = "sound/";
            var extention = ".wav";

            var audioIndex = 0;  

            annyang.debug(true);         
        };
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have logic errors in your code. When stopping and starting timers, you need to refer to the global variables.

This code isn't going to stop your timer:

```
function stopListening()
{
    var monitorId = 0;
    window.clearInterval(monitorId);
}
```

Your code also only initiates your play loop. It never starts the listening timer.

You logic will also play the first song twice.

To demonstrate the control flow, I have mocked the `audio` and `annyang` objects. The audio mock simulates the playing of 3 ten second audio files. When the window loads, the first audio mock will play. After which the annyang and the listening timer will start.

To mock annyang's sound detect there is a "mock sound" button. If it is clicked it will extend sound detection for another 3 seconds. Once 3 seconds goes by annyang will be paused and the next audio is played.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Annyang Mock</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var AudioMock = function () {
            this.src = null;
            this.start = null;
            this.timer = 0;
            var that = this;
            this.load = function () {
                $('#AudioState').html("Loaded " + that.src);
            }
            this.play = function () {
                that.start = new Date();

                $('#AudioState').html("Playing: " + this.src);

                window.setTimeout(that.end, 10000);
                that.timer = window.setInterval(that.mockPlayTime, 500);
            }
            this.mockPlayTime = function () {
                var d = new Date();
                var elapsed = (d - that.start) / 1000;
                $('#AudioState').html("Playing: " + that.src + " " + elapsed + " secs");
            }
            this.endMockPlayTime = function () {
                window.clearInterval(that.timer);
            }
            this.end = function () {
                that.endMockPlayTime();
                $('#AudioState').html("Ended: " + that.src);
                if (that.ended) {
                    that.ended();
                }
            }
            this.ended = null;
        };

        var annyangMock = function () {
            this.callbacks = {};
            this.paused = false;
        };


        annyangMock.prototype.addCallback = function (name, callback) {
            this.callbacks[name] = callback;

        }
        annyangMock.prototype.removeCallback = function (name, callback) {
            this.callbacks[name] = null;
        }
        annyangMock.prototype.pause = function () {
            $('#AnnyangState').html("Annyang: pause()");
            this.paused = true;
        }
        annyangMock.prototype.start = function () {
            $('#AnnyangState').html("Annyang: start()");
            this.paused = false;
        }
        annyangMock.prototype.invoke = function (name) {


            if (!this.paused) {
                $('#AnnyangState').html("called(" + name + ")");
                var cb = this.callbacks[name];
                if (cb) cb();
            }
        }
        annyangMock.prototype.debug = function (flag) { };

        var annyang = new annyangMock();



        var annyangMock = function () {
            var callbacks = {};
            var _paused = false;
            var pause = function () {
                $('#AnnyangState').html("Annyang: pause()");
                _paused = true;
            }
            function addCallback(name, callback) {
                callbacks[name] = callback;
            }
            function removeCallback(name, callback) {
                callbacks[name] = null;
            }
            function invoke(name) {
                $('#AnnyangState').html("called(" + name + ")");
                if (name == "start") {
                    _paused = false;
                }
                else {
                    if (!_paused) {
                        var cb = callbacks[name];
                        if (cb) cb();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
    <script>

        audio = new AudioMock();
        var monitorId = 0;
        if (annyang) {
            annyang.addCallback('start', function () { console.log('started listening!'); });
            annyang.addCallback('soundstart', onSoundHeard);

            function monitorSound() {
                lastSound = new Date();
                if (monitorId && monitorId > 0) return;
                monitorId = window.setInterval(trackSound, 1000);
                annyang.start();
            }

            var lastSound = new Date();
            function onSoundHeard() {
                lastSound = new Date();
                //console.log(lastSound);
            }

            function trackSound() {
                var now = new Date();
                var elapsed = now - lastSound;
                $('#AnnyangState').html("Listening: " + (elapsed / 1000) + " secs");
                if ((now - lastSound) > 3000) {
                    stopListening();
                    playNextAudio();
                    return;
                }
            }

            function stopListening() {

                window.clearInterval(monitorId);
                monitorId = 0;
                annyang.pause();

            }



            function playNextAudio() {
                if (audioIndex === playList.length - 1) {
                    console.log("Played all audios");
                    return; // we have played all audio
                }
                else {
                    audio.src = dir + playList[++audioIndex] + extention;
                    load();
                    setTimeout(function () { play(); }, 1000);

                }

            }
            function load() {
                $($('#playlist li')[audioIndex]).addClass("loading");
                audio.load();
            }
            function play() {
                audio.play();
                $('#playlist li').removeClass("loading")
                var li = $('#playlist li')[audioIndex];
                $(li).addClass("playing");
            }
            function playFirstAudio() {
                annyang.pause();
                audio.src = dir + playList[audioIndex] + extention;
                load();
                audio.ended = function () {
                    $('#playlist li').removeClass("playing");
                    lastSound = new Date(); // set timestamp
                    monitorSound(); // poll sound detection
                }
                setTimeout(function () { play(); }, 1000);
                //console.log('First audio is playing');

            }



            // Start from here

            var playList = ["1_hello", "2_how_old", "3_what_did_you_make"];
            var dir = "sound/";
            var extention = ".wav";

            var audioIndex = 0;

            annyang.debug(true);
            $(document).ready(function () {
                playFirstAudio();
                var l = $("<ol>");
                playList.forEach(function (j) {
                    l.append($("<li>").html(j));

                });
                $('#playlist').append(l);
            })
        };
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #playlist li {
            width: 200px;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        div {
            padding: 15px;
        }

        #playlist li.playing {
            border: 1px solid green;
            background: #dedede;
        }

        #playlist li.loading {
            border: 1px solid red;
            background: #dedede;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <b>Annyang State:</b> <span id="AnnyangState"></span>
    </div>
    <div><b>Audio State:</b> <span id="AudioState"></span></div>
    <div id="playlist">
        <b>Playlist:</b>
    </div>


    <div id="Controls">
        <input id="MockSound" type="button" value="Mock Sound" onclick="annyang.invoke('soundstart');" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OMG... this is a professional programming. There are some functions that I never see. Guess I will have to study really hard for this. Thank you Alexander. I really appreciate it. I will take a look at it tonight due to some labs.

Comment: Alexander, Today I was trying to test out my program. But I just realized that annyang only support Android, not iOS devices. My plan is to use a smartPhone(Android and iOS) to access the website. Thus, I might need to reprogram everything... Do you have any suggestions? I found out that W3C speech regonition plugin can support these two OS... I found myself so stupid that I didn't check it first.

Comment: My boss just told me that since this API can work on Android, we can just keep doing this to test for now. But today, even if I try to use Android smartphone, it can't listen to anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Do the demos on the site work? Maybe its your phone?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. My plan is to use Android mobile device to open up the Chrome broswer and run the program. But it's not working. Any idea? Or other API to use?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. Even on my phone its doesn't work. It says "visit in a DESKTOP browser like chrome".

Comment: Is your smartphone Android?

Comment: would you mind helping me on a new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178008/start-running-speechsynthesis-api-on-my-android-and-safari-devices  And no one help me with this post and I learned a lot from you. So I should vote you for the best answer.