# Start running SpeechSynthesis API on my Android and Safari devices

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, speech-synthesis

I'm trying to make a web app with the SpeechSynthesis API to run my program after one click on start button and then start listening to the user on my Android and iOS devices. The user could speak anything to run the program. After that, I can play my audio files every three seconds. Below is my code so far. Is my logic wrong? I can't start my program after the click and hear any sound.

Another question is this SpeechSynthesis API could support Android and iOS devices, but when I saw some event such as 'soundstart event', it doesn't support Safari Mobile. What are their relationships? I got really confused. And the SpeechRecognition API only supports for Chrome browser but don't I need to user some event like soundstart?

Thank you for help in advance. I really appreciate it.

```
 <p id="msg" align="center"></p>

    <script>
        var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Hello");
        //window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);

        var supportMsg = document.getElementById('msg');

        if ('speechSynthesis' in window)
        {
            supportMsg.innerHTML = 'Your browser <strong>supports</strong> speech synthesis.';
            console.log("Hi");

            utterance.onstart = function(event) 
            {
                console.log('Hhhh')
            };


            var playList = ["1_hello", "2_how_old", "3_what_did_you_make"];
            var dir = "sound/";
            var extention = ".wav";
            audio.src = dir + playList[audioIndex] + extention;
            audio.load();

            var audioIndex = 0;
            setTimeout(function(){audio.play();}, 1000);


            window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);

        } 
        else 
        {



            supportMsg.innerHTML = 'Sorry your browser <strong>does not support</strong> speech synthesis.<br>Try this in <a href="https://www.google.co.uk/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html">Chrome Canary</a>.';
        }

        //window.speechSynthesis(utterance);

    </script>
    <div class="container">
        <button id="runProgram" onclick='utterance.onstart();' 
        class="runProgram-button">Start</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```js
function playAudio() {
  var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Help me with this code please?');
  msg.pitch = 0;
  msg.rate = .6;
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);



  var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  msg.voice = voices[10]; // Note: some voices don't support altering params
  msg.voiceURI = 'native';
  msg.volume = 1; // 0 to 1
  msg.rate = 1.2; // 0.1 to 10
  msg.pitch = 2; //0 to 2
  msg.text = 'Sure. This code plays "Hello World" for you';
  msg.lang = 'en-US';

  msg.onend = function(e) {
    var msg1 = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Now code plays audios for you');
    msg1.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(function(voice) { return voice.name == 'Whisper'; })[0];
   msg1.pitch = 2; //0 to 2
   msg1.rate= 1.2; //0 to 2
    // start your audio loop.
    speechSynthesis.speak(msg1);
    console.log('Finished in ' + e.elapsedTime + ' seconds.');
  };

  speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button id="runProgram" onclick='playAudio();' class="runProgram-button">Start</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I think so even if this sounds funny. This is a good hint. Thank you so much Alex. I will try to make this API working like what we did for annyang. Do you think I can make onClick = 'window.speechSynthesis.soundstart()' ? Also, what are the relationship between SpeechSynthesis and SpeechRecognition APIs? Cuz SpeechSynthesis can support Android and safari but SpeechRecognition can only support Chrome.

Comment: No. `SoundStart` is an event that fires when IT starts speaking like `onend` fires when IT is done. They aren't methods that you trigger directly. `speechSynthesis.speak` will fire `SoundStart` when it starts speaking. Both APIs are _**experimental**_ in Draft status. Google just has a jump on the rest in regards to recongition.

Comment: Thanks for replying , Alexander. I see. I wonder if I can adjust my audio file like pitch or rate, instead of using the IT to speak.

Comment: My example shows how to adjust pitch and rate. Check out the API documentation.

Comment: Alexander, would you mind checking this for me, please? I have learned a lot from you so I would give you the best answer for this one.